# How can I get all Ids for a Pinterest board?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, pinterest, pinterest-api

I'm trying to avoid using the Pinterest APIs since it seems like they have a limit, and ideally I'd be able to publically post the Chrome extension for free.

It seems like Pinterest boards have Ids and they Id numbers are created in chronological order (same order boards are organized in). So to navigate I would just have to get all pin ids in a board (or landing page) and then navigate using that id (which matches the URL).

So my question is how can I get all Ids for a Pinterest board?

Also I'm not sure if I would be able to get a users login for this, so is there a way to get them all from the DOM? Pinterest doesn't seem to render everything at once so I'm not sure how that could be done

I tried obtaining them from the DOM, but it seems to be dynamically rendered.

I looked at the public Pinterest APIs but they seem to be limited to 2000 API calls per day. Since my goal is to post a free Chrome extension, this doesn't seem the way to go.

Currently looking into other ideas, but wanted to get other developer's thoughts.